# Avoid full page reload on back button with history pushState api

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, pushstate, history.js

Currently I have a page(Ruby on Rails application) where i never want to reload the page fully. All the links are ajax partial page loads. I'm using history.pushState api to change the url accordingly when users navigate.

Eg: Clicking on a link "A" i do

```
history.pushState({}, null, 'a')
```

However on clicking browser back button, the browser is actually doing a full page reload of the previous page. 
I tried preventDefault on the popstae but still no luck. It reloads the page as well as does my ajax load.

```
window.onpopstate = function(e){
e.preventDefault(); 
//ajax load previous link
}
```

How do i prevent the browser from acting on back button and have my custom function to do the page load instead ?

Edit: An interesting behaviour i've noticed is that when i do the same

```
history.pushState({}, null, 'a')
```

on a simple html page, clicking the Back button doesn't actually try to reload the full page. Not sure why this is the case with my site.